# How to Invoke a parameter in a batch file with comma-delimiter

Tags: batch-file

I want to invoke a batch file with a comma-delimited paramater.  How can I achieved this?

I want it like this example.

I have a text.bat with the script:

```
@echo off
set test=%1
echo Sample %test% batch.
```

I want to run the batch like this:

```
c:\text.bat this,is,sample
```

and I am expecting a result like this:

```
Sample this,is,sample batch.
```

Any idea how I could achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: thanks for your comment. sorry, i'm just new here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Wow!  I didn't know commas behaved that way.

You have two options.

You can use this script:

```
@echo off
set test=%~1
echo Sample %test% batch.
```

And run it with:

```
C:\text.bat "this,is,test"
```

The `%~1` represents the first argument without quotes.  The quotes group the comma-delimited list as a single argument.

**Or**

You can use this script:

```
@echo off
set test=%*
echo Sample %test% batch.
```

And run it with:

```
C:\text.bat this,is,test
```

The `%*` represents the command line arguments as they were typed.

Comment: I just wrote a loop to shift all arguments even beyond %9 into a single variable but I got stuck because one paramwas `a,b` but `%*` is the best solution. Thanks.

Comment: not only `,` but also `;` and `=` because [they're all delimiters to cmd](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

Answer (score 14):

In Batch files the parameter delimiters are, besides spaces, comma, semicolon and equal sign, so there is no direct way to do that. The only option is to enclose the parameter between quotes: `c:\text.bat "this,is,sample"` and take the parameter with %~1 to eliminate the quotes: `set test=%~1`.

Comment: Your answer adds something valuable, which is the fact that commas, semicolons, and equal signs serve as parameter delimiters. (This explained to me why `shift` was splitting comma-separated strings.) The other answer does not say this. However, you say that the only option the original poster has is to use `%~1`. This is not true; another option (mentioned by the other answer) is to use `%*`. In that case, it doesn't matter whether the comma-separated list is wrapped in quotes.

Comment: @Alan: If you read the question, the OP is talking about "a parameter", that is, *one* parameter. The other answer requires to use _all parameters_ so, for example, there is no way to give more than one parameter with same form, like in `c:\text.bat "this,is,sample" "second,param,with,commas"`. The only way to do this is enclosing _each parameter_ in quotes and using `%~1` and `%~2`...

Comment: @Aacini, I see.